# SimpleDateFormatter won't parse!

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

Hello I am trying to use the SimpleDateFormatter to parse the date `Wed, 30 Jun 2010 15:07:06 CST`

I am using the following code

```
public static SimpleDateFormat postedformat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date newDate = new Date(posteformat.parse("Wed, 30 Jun 2010 15:07:06 CST"));
```

but I am getting an illegalArgumentException.  Please help!

Comment: Which line are you getting the IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: getting the exception on the parse call

Comment: By the way: don't use SimpleDateFormat as a constant. Due to a design issue with SimpleDateFormat, it can't be used safely by multiple threads at once. The safest way to avoid this problem is to always create a new instance of a SimpleDateFormat when you need to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`postedformat.parse()` returns a `Date`, and there is no `Date(Date)` constructor.

Presumably removing the call to `new Date`, so you say `Date newDate = poste....` will suffice

Comment: ... and if that's so, you just need to add .getTime() after the parsing expression in order to use the constructor new Date(Long).

Comment: Good catch! The parse result is already a Date object. But then I'd expected a compile time error, not a runtime problem. Could be a typo in the question.

Comment: @schwiz - ??? how did you get an (runtime) exception on the parse call in code that doesn't compile??

Comment: I didn't copy/paste that code I just typed it out to give an example of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your code fragment doesn't compile. This slight modification compiles and parses successfully:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat postedformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    Date newDate = postedformat.parse("Wed, 30 Jun 2010 15:07:06 CST");
    System.out.println("newDate = " + newDate);
}
```

This is using Java 6 on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `java.util.Date()` constructor that takes a `java.util.Date` as an argument

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormat {
    public static SimpleDateFormat postedformat = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Date newDate = postedformat.parse("Wed, 30 Jun 2010 15:07:06 CST");
            System.out.println("Date: " + newDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Date: Wed Jun 30 22:07:06 BST 2010
```

Comment: But you shouldn't be able to compile something with `new Date(new Date()))`

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc examples shows unescaped comma but for the US locale. So either try escaping the comma (as Aaron suggested) or use the other constructor and set the Locale:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
```

Another problem could be the timezone ('CST') which is deprecated on the on hand and ambigious on the other (as per javadoc of `java.util.TimeZone`). Test, if it works without the timezone attribute (in both the format String and the value).